# How to create a navbar with a sidebar button, that when clicked, the entire screen background becomes transparent dark, and sidebar sits on top of it?

Tags: html, css

This is what I want to have:

```
<div class="navbar">..</div>
<div>some random element</div>
<div>some random element</div>
<div>some random element</div>
```

My navbar has a sidebar nested inside, and when the sidebar opens, the height of the navbar becomes 100vh with a dark transparent background, and the sidebar slides in, but the 100vh height pushes down all the sibling elements, and I don't want that. I want when you click the button to open the sidebar, the entire screen to become transparent dark, but I don't want to push down the below sibling elements. How do I achieve this?

I have tried making the navbar absolute with top and bottom 0, but then the below sibling elements are at the top of the page, and behind the navbar. Margin-bottom would not work because position absolute takes the element outside the context.

This is an example of what I want:

[image: Navbar]

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this? if yes, please include it in your question.
StackOverflow is made so its users can debug eachother's code. And finally, avoid making posts like this because it describes what you want in an abstract way, we're not here to guess what you precisely want. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @KyloDev I've included a screenshot of what I want. I already explained what I have tried in order to achieve this. It is included at the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your navbar inside a `div` and give it the same height as the height of your navbar. Now even when your navbar is positioned absolutely, the wrapper `div` will prevent the siblings from jumping up.

Comment: Okay, so far this is the only workable decent solution. There are still some issues with it. Such as the fact that the navbar `height` changes slightly on different resolutions, which I suppose I can fix, but another question I have is, when the user clicks the burger button again to close the sidebar, the `show` class is removed, and the `height 100vh` is removed, so the `height` collapses, and the sidebar does not slide out, but instead just disappears instantly. How can I prevent this, and make sure the sidebar slides out the same way it slided in?

Comment: @user21616350 The way I have made this in one of my project is to keep the navbar at same height and simply use `position: absolute` on the sidebar element nested inside of it. You can make it such that when navbar has `show` class which you can toggle through JS, the sidebar will have `transform: translateX(0)`, otherwise `translateX(100%)` to move it offscreen. You can use `transition` for slide in animation.

Comment: I fixed it by adjusting the height on each breaking point. Thanks a lot.